# Make a list of pairs given sets of a relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Make a list of pairs for the relation R from the set A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} to the set B = {0, 1, 2, 3} such that (a, b) ∈ R if and only if a - b < 1.

How would "a - b < 1" play into determining the points?

Comment: It defines which pairs are in $R$. Is $\langle 2,1\rangle\in R$? No, because $2-1$ is not less than $1$. Are $\langle 2,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,3\rangle$ in $R$? Yes, because $2-2$ and $2-3$ are less than $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a defining property shared by all of the elements in $R$, which is a subset of $A\times B$.  Let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  $(a,b)\in R$ if and only if $a-b<1$.

$R = \{(a,b)\in A \times  B : a-b<1 \}$

$R = \{(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3) \}$.